# Convert d3v6 Observable example using zoom.center

Tags: javascript, d3.js, zooming

I have a project where I'm trying to zoom to specific points. In d3v3, I could do that with this function

```
function zoomTo(place, pscale) {
  
  projection = d3.geo.mercator()
        .scale((1 << pscale) / 2 / Math.PI)
        .translate([width / 2, height / 2])
    
  center = projection(place);

return zoom
  .scale(projection.scale() * 2 * Math.PI)
  .translate([width - center[0], height - center[1]]);

}
```

Zoom has changed, though, and this no longer works in d3v6.

I found an example on Observable that does exactly what I want using d3v6:
https://observablehq.com/d/9035ed7049aaa8c6

However, I'm not sure how to translate it to vanilla javascript.
Below is my attempt. I'm getting this error:

```
d3.zoom(...).scaleExtent(...).on(...).center is not a function
```

It runs fine in Observable, though, so clearly I'm missing something. Any help would be greatly appreciated!
(Also, I don't need the buttons that are at the top of the Observable example, so I commented those out.)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Zoom to Point</title>
    <script src="https://files-7y4qaclbi.vercel.app/d3-zoom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <script>

        // const form = html`<form>
        //   <button name="in" type="button">Zoom In</button>
        //   <button name="out" type="button">Zoom Out</button>
        //   <button name="random" type="button">Random</button>
        //   <button name="reset" type="button">Reset</button>
        // </form>`;
        //   form.in.onclick = () => chart.zoomIn();
        //   form.out.onclick = () => chart.zoomOut();
        //   form.random.onclick = () => chart.zoomRandom();
        //   form.reset.onclick = () => chart.zoomReset();
        //   return form;

        const radius = 6

        const step = radius * 5

        const width = 500
        const height = 500

        const theta = Math.PI * (3 - Math.sqrt(5))

        const data = Array.from({ length: 1000 }, (_, i) => {
            const radius = step * Math.sqrt(i += 0.5), a = theta * i;
            return [
                width / 2 + radius * Math.cos(a),
                height / 2 + radius * Math.sin(a)
            ];
        })

        const quadtree = d3.quadtree()
            .addAll(data)

        // let mutable debug = undefined;

        let focussed;

        function findCloser(that, coords) {
            const p = d3.zoomTransform(that).invert(coords);
            focussed = quadtree.find(p[0], p[1]);
            return d3.zoomTransform(that).apply(focussed);
        }

        const zoom = d3
            .zoom()
            .scaleExtent([1, 40])
            .on("zoom", zoomed)
            .center(function (event, d) {
                // mutable debug = { event, d, r: Math.random() };
                let coords = d3.pointer(event, this);
                focussed = null;

                if (event.deltaY < 0) {
                    coords = findCloser(this, coords);
                }

                g.selectAll("circle").attr("r", p =>
                    p == focussed ? radius + 3 : radius
                );

                return coords;
            });

        const svg = d3.select('body').append("svg")
            .attr('width', width)
            .attr('height', height)
            .on("click", reset);

        const g = svg.append("g");

        g.selectAll("circle")
            .data(data)
            .join("circle")
            .attr("cx", ([x]) => x)
            .attr("cy", ([, y]) => y)
            .attr("r", radius)
            .attr("fill", (d, i) => d3.interpolateRainbow(i / 360))
            .on("click", clicked);

        svg.datum("I'm your worst datum").call(zoom); //.on("mousemove", mousemove);

        function random() {
            const [x, y] = data[Math.floor(Math.random() * data.length)];
            svg
                .transition()
                .duration(2500)
                .call(
                    zoom.transform,
                    d3.zoomIdentity
                        .translate(width / 2, height / 2)
                        .scale(40)
                        .translate(-x, -y)
                );
        }

        function reset() {
            svg
                .transition()
                .duration(750)
                .call(
                    zoom.transform,
                    d3.zoomIdentity,
                    d3.zoomTransform(svg.node()).invert([width / 2, height / 2])
                );
        }

        function clicked(event, [x, y]) {
            event.stopPropagation();
            svg
                .transition()
                .duration(750)
                .call(
                    zoom.transform,
                    d3.zoomIdentity
                        .translate(width / 2, height / 2)
                        .scale(40)
                        .translate(-x, -y),
                    d3.pointer(event, svg.node())
                );
        }

        function zoomed(event) {
            g.attr("transform", event.transform);
        }

        // return Object.assign(svg.node(), {
        //     zoomIn: () =>
        //         svg
        //             .transition()
        //             .call(zoom.scaleBy, 2, findCloser(svg.node(), [width / 2, height / 2])),
        //     zoomOut: () => svg.transition().call(zoom.scaleBy, 0.5),
        //     zoomRandom: random,
        //     zoomReset: reset
        // });
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Here it is in a Plunker, as well, if that's helpful: https://plnkr.co/edit/JaiKhTgEXzIFWiar?open=lib%2Fscript.js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no `zoom.center` in any d3-zoom release, from the first one to the current (v3.0.0 at the time of writing).

That `zoom.center` method was created by that Observable's author, which actively contributes to D3 ([see here](https://github.com/orgs/d3/people)). You can see the proposal here: https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom/pull/212

However, if you inspect [the code the author is using](https://files-7y4qaclbi.vercel.app/d3-zoom.js), you'll see that adding your own `center` method is not complicated. All you need is:

```
zoom.center = function(_) {
    return arguments.length ? (center = typeof _ === "function" ? _ : constant([+_[0], +_[1]]), zoom) : center;
  };
```

...and...

```
function defaultCenter(event) {
  return d3Selection.pointer(event, this);
}
```

With a couple of `center.apply(this, arguments)` that you can find by having a look at that file.

Comment: Ok, ok, I know you wrote *in any* ***d3-zoom***  *release*. For the sake of completeness, though, it's fair to note that there has been a [`zoom.center()`](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/9cc9a875e636a1dcf36cc1e07bdf77e1ad6e2c74/src/behavior/zoom.js#L108-L112) method in v3 for handling mousewheel actions. That method looked similar to the implementation you mention but could only handle constant values.